# AWS Codebuild - Dockerfile COPY issue: No such file or directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, dockerfile, aws-codebuild

I have an zip folder as project source (S3) defined. With following structure:

- Dockerfile
- buildspec.yml
- src

The Dockerfile is recognized by the build process and it only fails when trying to execute following Dockerfile command:

**COPY src/ /deploy/src/**

(Also not working: ./src/ or src)

Error:

> ```
> Step 6/9 : COPY src/ /deploy/src/
> COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder688322372/src: no such file or directory
> ```

Weirdly its working like this:

COPY src* /deploy/src/

.. then the build is successful and i get the image pushed on ECR. But when i exec into the running container the of course my file names inside the src folder are messed up. Each file will have src in front of the file name. Like in the conf folder: src\filexyz.json --> I need them to stay like filexyz.json

Any ideas how to solve this? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by uploading src as an tar-archive and using ADD in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Little more explanation would have helped me